# How to use BRISK in OpenCV?

Tags: algorithm, opencv

I can`t find any information of how to use BRISK key points detector and extractor in OpenCV on C/C++. If anybody knows, please, write the code or give a reference. Thanks!

P.S.:And how to use it in OpenCV 2.4.3?

Comment: I thought this was a perfectly reasonable question. You guys closing this as "not constructive" just don't happen to have this problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another way to get brisk in OpenCV 2.4.3

include header file "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp" where brisk class is implemented

//read some images in gray scale

```
const char * PimA="box.png";   // object
const char * PimB="box_in_scene.png"; // image

cv::Mat GrayA =cv::imread(PimA);
cv::Mat GrayB =cv::imread(PimB);

std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypointsA, keypointsB;
cv::Mat descriptorsA, descriptorsB;
```

//set brisk parameters

```
int Threshl=60;
int Octaves=4; (pyramid layer) from which the keypoint has been extracted
float PatternScales=1.0f;
```

//declare a variable BRISKD of the type cv::BRISK

```
cv::BRISK  BRISKD(Threshl,Octaves,PatternScales);//initialize algoritm
BRISKD.create("Feature2D.BRISK");

BRISKD.detect(GrayA, keypointsA);
BRISKD.compute(GrayA, keypointsA,descriptorsA);

BRISKD.detect(GrayB, keypointsB);
BRISKD.compute(GrayB, keypointsB,descriptorsB);
```

Declare one  type off matcher

```
cv::BruteForceMatcher<cv::Hamming> matcher;
```

another match that can be use

```
//cv::FlannBasedMatcher matcher(new cv::flann::LshIndexParams(20,10,2));


 std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
 matcher.match(descriptorsA, descriptorsB, matches);

    cv::Mat all_matches;
    cv::drawMatches( GrayA, keypointsA, GrayB, keypointsB,
                         matches, all_matches, cv::Scalar::all(-1), cv::Scalar::all(-1),
                         vector<char>(),cv::DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
    cv::imshow( "BRISK All Matches", all_matches );
    cv::waitKey(0);

    IplImage* outrecog = new IplImage(all_matches);
    cvSaveImage( "BRISK All Matches.jpeg", outrecog );
```

you can also use: Common Interfaces of Feature Detectors

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::Algorithm::create<cv::FeatureDetector>("Feature2D.BRISK");

detector->detect(GrayA, keypointsA);
detector->detect(GrayB, keypointsB);

cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> descriptorExtractor =cv::Algorithm::create<cv::DescriptorExtractor>("Feature2D.BRISK");

descriptorExtractor->compute(GrayA, keypointsA, descriptorsA);
descriptorExtractor->compute(GrayB, keypointsB, descriptorsB);
```

the result with this code is like at this
http://docs.opencv.org/_images/Feature_Description_BruteForce_Result.jpg